# Print next element of a list, if it matches the previous element

Tags: python, list

I have a list with similar elements, and I want to print the next element if I match the previous one.
So  something like this:

```
my_list=['one', 'two', 'one', 'one', 'two']
for ml in my_list:
    if ml =='one':
        print (next)
```

so the output would be:

```
two

two
```

Comment: Shouldn't that print `two`, `one`, `two`?

Comment: short answer: make use of list indices using enumerate(my_list)

Comment: Not wasting an answer on this; just do this:
```my_list=['one', 'two', 'one', 'one', 'two']
for i, ml in enumerate(my_list):
    if ml == 'one' and i != len(my_list):
        print(my_list[i+1])```

Comment: @Aran-Fey no only two

Comment: @Noxeus, would it work for a longer list with more different elements?

Comment: Why? Why only `two`?

Comment: Aran-Fey is right though, using your pseudo-code that would be the output

Comment: I edited my comment as to include not getting an exception if we're at the end of the list. And yes that would work for any length.

Comment: @Noxeus it still printing two one two

Comment: Well in your list you have `one, one` so it will print `one`. If you don't want to print that *even though* the next item is `one` you have to change your code.

Comment: @Aran-Fey sorry didn't get your question, your are right it gives two one two

Comment: @Noxeus that's why I'm asking a question, what is missing in my code, to do it...

Comment: No you're asking to print the next item if the current is `one`. You never stated it should'nt print if the next value == `one`. But fine, add this: `and mylist[i+1] != 'one'` to the if statement.

Comment: @Noxeus Thank you, it seems to work. but I wrote on my question that the output I need is two two...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
my_list=['one', 'two', 'one', 'one', 'two']
i = 0
for ml in my_list:
    if ml =='one' and i!=(len(my_list)-1):
        print (my_list[i+1])
    i+=1
```

Output:

```
two
one
two
[Finished in 0.0s]
```

Answer (score 1):

This code should do what you want:

```
my_list=['one', 'two', 'one', 'one', 'two']
for i, item in enumerate(my_list):
    if i != 0:
        if item == my_list[i-1]:
            print(my_list[i+1])
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are looking to print only `two`. So you need to check if the next value is also not `one`.

```
my_list=['one', 'two', 'one', 'one', 'two']
for i, ml in enumerate(my_list):
  if ml =='one' and my_list[i+1] != 'one':
     print (my_list[i+1])
```

The output of this will be:

```
two
two
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `zip` function to get adjacent pairs:

```
for a, b in zip(my_list[:-1], my_list[1:]):
  if a == "one":
    print(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would actually say a more elegant solution to this problem would be to first convert your `list` of words into a `string`

`' '.join(my_list)`

and then split it on the word 'one' like so

`my_string.split('one')`

as this would give you a list of all the subsequent words after each 'one' .

`>>> ['', ' two ', ' ', ' two']`

In summary, a simple one-line solution would be:

`' '.join(my_list).split('one')`